# How to extract shared logic out of multimethods?

Tags: clojure

Given the multimethods below -

```
(defmulti group-data :group-by)

(defmethod group-data :day
  [kv]
  (->> kv :data (group-by
                 (fn [kv]
                   (let [date (:time kv)]
                     (str
                      (month date) "-" (day date) "-" (year date)))))))

(defmethod group-data :month
  [kv]
  (->> kv :data (group-by
                 (fn [kv]
                   (let [date (:time kv)]
                     (str
                      (month date) "-" (year date)))))))

(defmethod group-data :year
  [kv]
  (->> kv :data (group-by
                 (fn [kv]
                   (let [date (:time kv)]
                     (year date))))))
```

In all the three multimethods the only difference is the string function. How do I create a higher order function, where it will just take different s expression for creating the string ?

Also any better ideas for reducing the repeated code ?

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes you don't need multimethods:

```
(def dmap {:day #(str (month %) "-" (day %) "-" (year %))
           :month #(str (month %) "-" (year %))
           :year #(year %)})

(defn group-data [kv]
  (->> kv :data (group-by
                 (fn [kv]
                   (let [date (:time kv)]
                     ((dmap (:group-by kv)) date))))))
```

Comment: hey this is really cool ! Using a map to store functions and then retrieving them as needed. So my next question is when should I choose a multimethod over the above?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest answer is to define a function containing all the shared logic, which takes in another function used to fill in the "hole" that varies:

```
(defn helper [kv time-fn]
  (->> kv :data (group-by
                 (fn [kv]
                   (let [date (:time kv)]
                     (timefn data))))))

(defmulti group-data :group-by)

(defmethod group-data :day
  [kv]
  (helper kv (fn [date]
               (str (month date) "-" (day date) "-" (year date)))))

(defmethod group-data :month
  [kv]
  (helper kv
          (fn [date]
            (str (month date) "-" (year date)))))

(defmethod group-data :year
  [kv]
  (helper kv year))
```

Answer (score 2):

@amalloy beat me to the bunch, but the structure of our solutions are a little different, so I'll add mine too.

As always, when there's duplicate logic, it's time to think about wrapping it up in a function. In our case, rather than returning values directly, the multimethod could return the algorithm used to `group-by`. Then, `group-data` can be written as a regular function which uses the multimethod to determine *how* it groups.

```
(defmulti group-by-algorithm :group-by)

(defn group-data
  [kv]
  (->> kv :data (group-by (group-by-algorithm kv))))

(defmethod group-by-algorithm :day
  [_]
  (fn [{date :time}] ; destructuring kv to save us a `let`
    (str
      (month date) "-" (day date) "-" (year date))))

 (defmethod group-by-algorithm :month
  [_]
  (fn [{date :time}]
     (str
       (month date) "-" (year date))))

(defmethod group-by-algorithm :year
 [_]
 (fn [{date :time}]
   (year date)))
```

This solution lets the algorithms return anything and is generally applicable. However, assuming every algorithm returns some dash-separated string of values based on the date, we can reduce the boilerplate even more by introducing a function which takes the functions that produce values and produces the dash-separated string by calling them in turn.

```
(defmulti fns-to-group-by :group-by)

(defn group-by-algorithm
  [group-by-fns]
  (fn [{date :time}]
    (->>
      (map #(%1 date) group-by-fns) ; Call each function on the date
      (interpose "-") ; Separate by dashes
      (apply str)))) ; And mush them into a string

(defn group-data
  [kv]
  (->> kv :data (group-by (group-by-algorithm (fns-to-group-by kv)))))

(defmethod fns-to-group-by :day
  [_]
  [month day year])

 (defmethod fns-to-group-by :month
  [_]
  [month year])

(defmethod fns-to-group-by :year
 [_]
 [year])
```

Comment: this is really cool. You are placing the complexity where it should be.

Answer (score 1):

3 answers already and no mention of macros :) .. I know there are obvious reasons to prefer higher order functions but macros deserve at least one answer, so here it is:

```
(defmacro group-by-template [date-symbol expression coll]
  `(group-by
      (fn [kv#]
        (let [~date-symbol (:time kv#)]
          ~expression)) ~coll))

(defmulti group-data :group-by)

(defmethod group-data :day
  [kv]
  (->> kv :data (group-by-template date (str (month date) "-" (day date) "-" (year date)))))

(defmethod group-data :month
  [kv]
  (->> kv :data (group-by-template date (str (month date) "-" (year date)))))

(defmethod group-data :year
  [kv]
  (->> kv :data (group-by-template date (year date))))
```

Comment: Macros are more powerful than necessary for this problem, but at least if you're going to use macros you should try to reduce the amount of wasted typing: https://gist.github.com/amalloy/5084918

Comment: @amalloy: Nice..I didn't knew about macrolet.